# Replace Input box with Looping function

Tags: excel, vba

So I'd like to create a looping function - where
If the response in Column O is 'Yes' input the value in Column C as the 'new name' of the copied sheet
Loop until Column O is blank

I know I have to remove the Inputbox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
However I'm not sure what to put after newname as the looping function

```
Sub Button112_Click()

Dim newName As String

On Error Resume Next
newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
If newName <> "" Then


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    Range("$D$3").Value = newName
End If

Dim n As Name
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
n.Visible = True
Next n

Dim numrow
numrow = Range("F16").Value

If IsNumeric(numrow) Then

For i = 1 To numrow

Call INRW

Next i
End If

End Sub
```

I've tried something similar to this, but with no success

```
   lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 15).Value2 = "Yes" Then CopySheetAndRename (.Cells(i, 3).Value2)
        Next i
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear how your posted code relates to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'er after something like this:

```
Sub Button112_Click()

    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    With Worksheets("mySheetName")'change mySheetName to suit your needs

        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 15).Value2 = "Yes" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = .Cells(i, 3).Value2
                Range("$D$3").Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value2
            End If
        Next

    End With

    .... 
    rest of your code
```